# Struts 2 and locale question

Tags: java, struts2

I've got forms that I display on almost every pages of a website (a login form, for example), so I don't use an action for those. The "post" of those forms just goes to an action and if there is a validation error, it displays another "central" page. The only thing that doesn't seems to work in the form page is displaying a message in different languages using the tag `<s:text>`

It always use the default locale defined in struts.properties. I guess it's because I don't call any action before displaying the form.

Anyway, I have 2 files : `struts_fr.properties` and `struts_en.properties`

In `struts.properties` I have

```
struts.locale = fr_CA
```

And I use something like :

```
<s:text name="login.label.username" />
```

The message displayed is always the one from the "struts_fr.properties".

**The question is : How can I set the locale for struts, before using the s:text tag, when there is no action called?**

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems that it worked "alone" after a while... maybe the work directory was in cause here. We also have some custom interceptor so maybe that's why it worked.